# Scala Skinny ORM Soft Deletion get deleted records

Tags: scala, playframework

I have moving from PHP ORM (Laravel Eloquent) to Scala. And I have found that the most similar to Eloquent is the Skinny ORM.
After use it to create simple CRUD application, I found problem about how to get the records that deleted using soft deletion?

I also check on the code inside the Skinny ORM and seems they don't support it, not sure if I can not find it or they really don't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was implement the with delete by self.
Here the trait I made :

```
trait SoftDelete[Entity] extends CRUDFeatureWithId[Long, Entity] {

  /**
   * deleted_at timestamp field name.
   */
  def deletedAtFieldName = "deletedAt"

  var withDeletion = false;

  def withDeleted = {
    withDeletion = true
    this
  }

  override def defaultScopeForUpdateOperations: Option[SQLSyntax] = {
    val c = defaultAlias.support.column
    val scope = sqls.isNull(c.field(deletedAtFieldName))
    if(withDeletion)
      super.defaultScopeForUpdateOperations
    else
      super.defaultScopeForUpdateOperations.map(_.and.append(scope)) orElse Some(scope)
  }

  override def defaultScope(alias: Alias[Entity]): Option[SQLSyntax] = {
    val scope = sqls.isNull(alias.field(deletedAtFieldName))
    if(withDeletion)
      super.defaultScope(alias)
    else
      super.defaultScope(alias).map(_.and.append(scope)) orElse Some(scope)
  }

  override def deleteBy(where: SQLSyntax)(implicit s: DBSession = autoSession): Int = {
    updateBy(where).withNamedValues(column.field(deletedAtFieldName) -> DateTime.now)
  }
}
```

And we can call the Model with deleted like this :

```
User.withDeleted.findAll
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, because there is no way for me to edit directly on the library